# Getting error when trying to extract data from SQL with SPRING BOOT

Tags: spring-boot

I am trying to see if there is already existing account with this email in database,when someone is trying to register in the application. When i try this i get Error 500

> Message Request processing failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a];
> nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet

this is my user repository

```
  package com.jrp.site.repositories;
  import java.util.List;

  import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
  import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
  import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
  import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

  import com.jrp.site.vehicles.UserAccount;

  @Repository
  public interface UserAccountRepository extends CrudRepository<UserAccount,Long>{


  @Override
  List<UserAccount> findAll();


  @Query(nativeQuery=true,value="SELECT * FROM user_Accounts where user_Accounts.email = :email" )
  List<UserAccount> existsByUsername(@Param("email") String email);
```

Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user_accounts")
@Service
public class UserAccount {



@Id
//@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator="user_accounts")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="user_accounts_seq")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "user_accounts_seq", sequenceName = "user_accounts_seq", allocationSize = 1)
@Column(name="user_id")
private long userId;

@Column(name="username")
private String userName;

private String email;
private String password;

private boolean enabled=true;
```

And this is simple HTML just for test

```
 <!DOCTYPE html> 
<html  xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">   
<body>   
<form action = "/loginon">   
    <div name="email" >
    
    <input type = "text"> </input>

    </div>

<button type="submit">click me</button> 

 </form>

</body>
```

Comment: The SQLGrammarException is thrown because the SQL query generated by Hibernate has wrong SQL syntax. Just have a recheck on
 `@Query(nativeQuery=true,value="SELECT * FROM user_Accounts where user_Accounts.email = :email" )`

Comment: Hmm, I have thought about this, and tried different options but without progress. I will try it again, thanks for answer.